# How do I  install 4shared?

Tags: installation

My Linux is Edubuntu 12.04 LTS. After downloaded & installing successfully "desktop4shared-1.3_1-all" package, 4shared doesn't work on my platform.

Comment: Why doesn't work? I mean what logs do you have? Error messages?

Answer (score 2):

The [4shared package](https://www.4shared.com/file/x3JqSRo1/desktop4shared-13_1-all.html) has a LOT of dependencies (additional packages required to run), including Java and other Java libraries. If you install the .deb with Software Center or gdebi, all the dependencies should be automatically installed.

If not, or if your Ubuntu variant doesn't use Software Center, do this:

1. Open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`.
2. Type the following, one line at time, and enter your password whenever prompted:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i desktop4shared-1.3_1-all.deb
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
3. Go to the Launcher and type "4Shared" to start it:

   [image]