# How to install 4shared Desktop on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: software-installation

How do I install [4shared](https://www.4shared.com/) desktop apps on Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Does it have a native version for Ubuntu/Linux? If so, in what file format?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

4shared offers a Deb package, but not easy to found:

https://dc346.4shared.com/download/x3JqSRo1

Open your terminal and install the package:

```
# Download the package
wget https://dc346.4shared.com/download/x3JqSRo1 -O desktop4shared-all.deb

# Install the package
sudo apt install ./desktop4shared-all.deb
```

Source : [How do I  install 4shared?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163455/how-do-i-install-4shared/246738)

Comment: Tried in 16.04. It installs all right (along with 30 dependencies!!!) but doesn't run. Not entirely unexpected considering how old it is.

Comment: server connection failed